# EntityFramework Core 1.1.0 missing Include()?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am using EntityFramework Core 1.1.0. I can query a table and load entities, but the instructions from Microsoft indicates if I want to load relational data, I should use the `.Include()` function:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data

> You can use the `Include` method to specify related data to be included in query results. In the following example, the blogs that are returned in the results will have their `Posts` property populated with the related posts.
>
> ```
> using (var context = new BloggingContext())
> {
>     var blogs = context.Blogs
>         .Include(blog => blog.Posts)
>         .ToList();
> }
> ```

I have no `.Include()` option.

Any ideas why this is missing or how to load foreign-key relational data?

```
this.context.Mail
    .Include("Files") // This is missing
```

I have resorted to explicitly loading relational data. This is fine for small result sets, but as my data sets grow, this is going to cause me grief.

```
var mails = this.context.Mail.ToList();
mails.ForEach(mail =>
{
    this.context.Entry(mail)              
    .Collection(m => m.Files)
    .Load();
});
```

Comment: Could you show us how you have modelled the relational tables in the Mail-class?

Comment: Dai.. Your edit applies to EF6 and lower. I am using EF-Core... There appears to be no "Include()"  option for the DbSet in that version.

Comment: Dai... I may be missing a nuget package, but from what I can see, there is no Include() in Entity Framework Core. I know the docs you shared say they are for Core and I have read those several times today... Those docs are the reason I am asking this question... It says to use Include(), but I don't have that option.

Comment: To notificate somebody, you need this sytax: @Dai. I have done this for you now. Also, he just improved your question, because you missed to give a source of your research. (*Microsoft indicates if I want to load relational data, I should use the .Include() function*)

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt - Thanks for your tips! I am fairly new to asking questions here. I see how he was not attempting an answer.

Comment: @birwin I linked to EF Core documentation, not EF6 documentation.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Have you included the correct namespaces?

[From the repository linked in the documentation](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework.Docs/blob/master/samples/core/Querying/Querying/RelatedData/Sample.cs):

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: Microsoft Renames Entity Framework namespaces announcement:
https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/144

Answer (score 2):

Add the namespace to get that option.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
```

and also if you haven't added,

```
using System.Linq;
```

If you enable the lazy loading then you don't even need to use include.

Answer (score 1):

I think your call should be:

```
this.context.Mail
    .Include(m => m.Files).ToList();
```

For a more detailed answer:
You need to first make sure that your `Mail` and `File` models are formed correctly so that there is a one-to-many relationship between `Mail` and `File`:

```
public class Mail
{
    public int MailId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<File> Files { get; set; }
}

public class File
{
    public int FileId { get; set; }

    public int MailId { get; set; }
    public virtual Mail Mail { get; set; }
}
```

And then make sure to include `Mail` and `File` DbSet to your DbContext:

```
public class MailingContext : DbContext
{
    public MailingContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Mail> Mails { get; set; }
    public DbSet<File> Files { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
    }
}
```

Then in your controller class or repository class, you can create a method to get Mails with Files like this:

```
public IList<Mail> GetMails()
{
    return _context.Mails.Include(m => m.Files).ToList();
}

public Mail GetMailById(int id)
{
    return _context.Mails.Include(m => m.Files).SingleOrDefault(m => m.MailId == id);
}
```