# ThenInclude not recognized in EF Core query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

My IQueryable looks like this:

```
 IQueryable<TEntity> query = context.Set<TEntity>();
query = query.Include("Car").ThenInclude("Model");
```

> 'IQueryable' does not contain a definition for 'ThenInclude'
>   and no extension method 'ThenInclude' accepting a first argument of
>   type 'IQueryable' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

I have all references needed:

```
using Content.Data.Models;    
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;    
using System;    
using System.Collections.Generic;    
using System.Linq;    
using System.Linq.Expressions;    
using System.Threading.Tasks;
```

Why it doesn't recognize ThenInclude?

Query:

```
[Content.Data.Models.Article]).Where(x => (((x.BaseContentItem.SiteId == value(Content.Business.Managers.ArticleManager+<>c__DisplayClass8_0).id) AndAlso x.BaseContentItem.IsActive) AndAlso x.BaseContentItem.IsLive)).Include("BaseContentItem").Include("BaseContentItem.TopicTag").Include("MainImage")}
```

Fails after I include `.Include("BaseContentItem.TopicTag")` part.

So I just read that with generic repository you lose ThenInclude. I am using thise generic rep:

```
public class ReadOnlyRepository<TContext> : IReadOnlyRepository
            where TContext : DbContext
    {
        protected readonly TContext context;

        public ReadOnlyRepository(TContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }

        private IQueryable<TEntity> GetQueryable<TEntity>(
            Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
            Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
            string includeProperties = null,
            int? skip = null,
            int? take = null)
            where TEntity : class, IEntity
        {
            includeProperties = includeProperties ?? string.Empty;
            IQueryable<TEntity> query = context.Set<TEntity>();

            if (filter != null)
            {
                query = query.Where(filter);
            }

            foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split
                (new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            {
                query = query.Include(includeProperty);
            }

            if (orderBy != null)
            {
                query = orderBy(query);
            }

            if (skip.HasValue)
            {
                query = query.Skip(skip.Value);
            }

            if (take.HasValue)
            {
                query = query.Take(take.Value);
            }

            return query;
        }
```

Comment: Does EF Core even have the methods `.Include(string)` and `.ThenInclude(string)`? Shouldn't it be `query = query.Include(e => e.Car).ThenInclude(e => e.Model);`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EntityFramework Core 1.1.0 missing Include()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42098706/entityframework-core-1-1-0-missing-include)

Comment: @DavidG Indeed. Or just `Include(dot_separated_string)`. But OP claims it doesn't work, and I can't recall having issues with dot separated property names `Include` from the time that overload has been introduced (1.1.0 if I remember correctly).

Comment: @IvanStoev Ah yes, that's a possibility. Never been a fan of the string based versions though as they lack compile time type checks.

Comment: Query built: [Content.Data.Models.Article]).Where(x => (((x.BaseContentItem.SiteId == value(Content.Business.Managers.ArticleManager+<>c__DisplayClass8_0).id) AndAlso x.BaseContentItem.IsActive) AndAlso x.BaseContentItem.IsLive)).Include("BaseContentItem").Include("BaseContentItem.TopicTag").Include("MainImage")} . It fails with stackoverflow when i include .Include("BaseContentItem.TopicTag")

Comment: It could be EF Core bug (you didn't specify EFC version used). Try removing `.Include("BaseContentItem")` because it's redundant - `.Includ‌​e("BaseContentItem.T‌​opicTag")` will include all parts of the path.

Comment: I am using EF Core 2.0 latest version. I now only included BaseContentItem.TopicTag and still same issue.

Comment: After you edit it's not clear what you're asking anymore.

Answer (score 46):

`ThenInclude` is available only when you use the `Include` overload with lambda expression parameter:

```
query = query.Include(e => e.Car).ThenInclude(e => e.Model);
```

When you use the `Include` overload with string argument, there is no need of `ThenInclude` since you can specify the whole property path in the passed string:

```
query = query.Include("Car.Model");
```

Comment: It works for me. Consider posting a repro (and specify the EF Core version - my test in on v2.0)

Comment: I opened new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46003275/how-to-make-generic-repository-working-with-theninclude-with-ef-net-core-2-0

Comment: I saw it. And what you wrote at the end makes me think that the stack overflow exception might not be caused by `Include` method (which as I said works in my tests), but by AutoMapper when `BaseContentItem.T‌​opicTag` is in effect (may be `TopicTag` has circular reference to `BaseContentItem` which is causing infinite cycle in mapping code). Could you verify if the query can be executed and materialized into List w/o calling `Map`?

Answer (score 13):

Your problem might be a missing reference to Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational?

This can be added through the package manager.

Also ensure you are using .include from the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore namespace and not the other .Include (which does not have a .ThenInclude)

Comment: Please [edit] to rephrase this into a conditional answer, like "Your problem might be ..., in which case the solution is to ....". The way this is currently phrased it risks being mistaken for a clarification question (which should be in a comment....).